# c# openXML add cross-reference to a table w:instrText

Tags: c#, openxml

I am trying to add caption to a table and I can't find what I am looking for on any other posts.

This is the XML I am trying to produce.

```
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> REF TableRef \h </w:instrText>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">Table </w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:fldSimple w:instr="SEQ Table">
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:noProof />
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:fldSimple>
            <w:r>
            <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

I cant figure out how to get the instrText part.

```
        <w:r>
            <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> REF TableRef \h </w:instrText>
        </w:r>
```

Here is 90% of the code, can someone fill out the todo for me.

```
      DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run run2 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(new Text() { Text = "Table ", Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve });
      SimpleField simpleField2 = new SimpleField(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(new RunProperties(new NoProof()), new Text() { Text = " ", Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve }));
      simpleField2.Instruction = @"SEQ " + "Table";

      DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph refP = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(new FieldChar() { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.Begin }),
        //todo instrTxt bookmark ref
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(new FieldChar() { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.Separate }),
        run2,
        simpleField2,
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(new FieldChar() { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.End })

        );
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at the Document Reflector included with the OpenXML SDK? Just create the desired output in Word and open that document using the Document Reflector. It will then show you the source code to produce that output.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I would have come across that earlier.  I never saw it in any of the examples I looked at.  Post it as the answer and I will give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues like writing the correct C# code that will produce a certain Open XML document can be solved easily using a sample document and the *Document Reflector* that comes with the Open XML SDK:

1. Download and install the latest version of the Open XML SDK ([OpenXMLSDKToolV25.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425))
2. Open the **Open XML SDK Productivity Tool** (`OpenXmlSdkTool.exe`) located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.5\tool` (when installed to the default location).
3. Create a sample document with the desired formatting/content and open your sample document in the tool.
4. Click on ***Reflect Code***
5. Copy the generated code to your project and adjust where needed, e.g. by replacing the static text with your content.

Answer (score 1):

For others stumbling upon this question years later. The OpenXml class corresponding to `<w:instrText>` is [`DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.FieldCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.fieldcode).

So to answer the original problem, the line:

```
//todo instrTxt bookmark ref
```

Should be replaced by:

```
new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(new FieldCode(" REF TableRef \\h ") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve }),
```

Where `TableRef` is the name of the bookmark.

Comment: Your intuition serves you well mate.